# Adding a dictionary for each object inside another dictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I've populated a uitableview from an NSMutableDictionary using this code to populate my dictionary:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)createDictionaryForSectionIndex:(NSArray *)array withSubtitle:(NSArray *)subtitle
{
   NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   for (char firstChar = 'a'; firstChar <= 'z'; firstChar++)
   {

    NSString *firstCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", firstChar];
    NSArray *content = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", firstCharacter]];
    NSMutableArray *mutableContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:content];

    if ([mutableContent count] > 0)
    {
        NSString *key = [firstCharacter uppercaseString];
        [dict setObject:mutableContent forKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%@: %lu", key, (unsigned long)[mutableContent count]);
    }
    NSLog(@"mutable content: %@", mutableContent);


}


return dict;
}
```

from this source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279408/1042801

I'm trying to add another key/value for each outputted key/value. It's somewhat difficult to articulate my thoughts, so here's an example of something that I think I need:

```
key => 'A'
object => {"Aardvark"
    object => {"mammal"}
, "Ape"
    object => {"mammal"}
, "Aquaman"
    object => {"superhero"}
}
//etc...
```

My table view should then be able to access those keys for each object above it to use as a detail text label for the cells in my table view. My apologies if what I'm trying to accomplish makes no sense, dictionaries aren't quite engrained in my repertoire yet.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the dictionary and then populate your UITableView with the dictionary ? I m correct?

Comment: That would be correct. I have, however, used an alternate method using some arrays and sets.

Comment: can you just show the code you have written in your cellFOrRowAtIndexPath? You just want to populate your table with the sorted data right? So you have to sort the dictionary and insert in an array, and populate your UITableView.